# Combining regular expressions in java

Tags: java, regex

What if I want to write a regex which says match [^some pattern] && [not this pattern]. So I want it to match some pattern but not a pattern [^\.\.] (not a double dot) in english

For example:

it shouldn't match:

../../

but it should match

hey/../

Comment: You ... make your regex exclusive of what you don't want.

Comment: Do you really mean [character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)? Can you give some specific examples of regular expressions and the results you want for those examples?

Comment: [Take a look at this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Comment: `[^\\.\\.]` does **not** mean "not a double dot." It just matches a single non-dot character (eg: equivalent to `[^.]`).

Comment: so what if I wan't not a double dot?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a negative [lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
^(?!excludepattern)includepattern
```

will match `includepattern` unless it would also match `excludepattern`.

For example,

```
^(?!\.\.)([\w.,]+/)+$
```

would match any slash-separated sequence of letters, digits, underscore, dot or comma, unless it starts with `..` (as in your example).

To address your comment (as I understand it), try this:

```
^(?!.*\.\.)[\w.]*$
```

This will match a string that consists entirely of alphanumeric characters or dots, but does not contain two dots in a row anywhere. It also matches the empty string.

Comment: looks as good as any interpretation of the question's answer <-- does that make sense?

Comment: I think what I basically want is to make sure that [\w.]+ is not a double dot

Comment: @xonegirlz: I added a new regex. Hope I understood your edit.